# Most reliable way to prove a graph is/isn't Hamiltonian?

Tags: graph-theory

What would be the most reliable (and preferably simplest) way to determine and prove if this graph is Hamiltonian or not?

My first thought was to try and draw out the circuit but I feel that can be easily done wrong?
I was also thinking of seeing if the graph includes all Hamiltonian properties?

Is this graph Hamiltonian and what was your approach?

Thanks

[image]

*Removed 3 middle vertices, resulting 4 components:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you delete the three middle vertices in the central row, the graph splits into four connected components. Therefore the graph does not have a Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: Oh, is your approach to dispute the proposition that "If G is a Hamiltonian graph, then deleting any K vertices from G results in a graph with a most K connected components?What would the resulting components look like?

Comment: Also if you delete the middle *five* vertices, the remaining graph has eight components, so it doesn't have a Hamiltonian path either.

Comment: @A825 I don't think that proposition is in dispute; it's just being applied to the graph you presented.

Comment: Ah I see, so if I remove the middle 3 vertices, what do the 4 components look like? I'm having a hard time visualising it

Comment: @A825 Well, two of the components are the single vertices above and below the central removed one. The other two components are whatever remains on the left and right sides.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I've added the photo to the original post, are they correct?

Comment: @A825 Not quite. Your components 3&4 still have copies of the vertices from components 1&2 (And what's with the edge they are connected with? You've somehow merged the edges from the other removed vertices)

Comment: @A825 You're also missing some horizontal edges.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I've added the horizontal lines and removed the other ones, fingers crossed its right now? Hahah

Comment: @A825 Yes, that looks correct now.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to prove that a Graph is Hamiltonian, by just finding any Hamiltonian path.

Proving the inverse is not that easy. The only way I know is to somehow argue logically that if you first choose one edge then you can't choose a specific other edge which will somehow give a contradiction. You can try argue using degrees of nodes as well.

However, there is no general approach, as finding a Hamiltonian path is a NP-complete problem - meaning it's probably not solvable in polynomial time.